# C# - How to prevent a reference being taken to a class member?

Tags: c#

I have a class (myClass) that contains a private class member (currentData of type myData).  I have a property (CurrentData) that allows "get"ting that member.  I want to allow users to call functions on currentData but prevent them from taking an external reference to it.  Eg.

```
myClass a = new myClass();

// This is OK
a.CurrentData.somefunc();

// This is what I dont want
myData m = new myData();
m = a.CurrentData;
// ... some time passes here...
m.someFunc();
```

While I understand they reference the same object.  I dont want a reference being kept outside of my class to an internal member as the internal member could change unexpectedly.

Is this possible?  I have been away from c# so long I cant remember how it all works!

Comment: sadly but not possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's not a way to make

```
a.CurrentData.somefunc();
```

legal but

```
m = a.CurrentData;
```

illegal.  `a.CurrentData.somefunc();`  essentially returns an inline reference to `a.CurrentData` and then calls `somefunc()` on that reference.

If you want to prevent references to the internal object then you'll have to add methods to the containing class that then pass through to the contained object:

```
public void DoSomeFuncWithCurrentData()
{
   this.currentData.someFunc();
}

myClass a = new myClass();

a.DoSomeFuncWithCurrentData();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to "forbid" references.

However, there are a few possible workarounds:

- Create **proxy methods**: Don't allow public access to the `CurrentData` property at all. Create a proxy method for every method that can be called on CurrentData:

  ```
  myClass a = new myClass();
  a.SomeFuncOnCurrentData();
  ```

  That way you don't expose the inner workings of your class to the outside. The drawback is that you have to write a lot of boilerplate code (or use some third-party tool which writes the boilerplate code for you).
- **Return a copy**: Replace your `CurrentData` property with a `GetCurrentData` method and return a *new copy* of your internal object on every invocation. That way, the user can operate on the "old" data as long as he wants, and the user's object is disconnected from your internal object.
- **Replace your internal object and leave the old one intact**: Make `MyData` an immutable class. When `CurrentData` changes, don't modify MyData, create a new MyData object instead. This has the same effect as the previous point (returning a copy), but you can keep using a property which does not need to create a copy on each invocation.
- **Invalidate the old internal object**: When `CurrentData` changes, perform the following steps:

  - internally use a new instance of `MyData`,
  - set a flag on the old instance, which causes `someFunc` to throw a `ObjectExpiredException`.

Comment: Another option is to return a wrapper object instead of the object itself

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent users from taking external references to an object, but you can do one of two things to make such references irrelevant:

- Make your inner object *immutable* - that way the external reference would have no possibility to change what is inside your object. This is what .NET library did with strings.
- Return a defensive copy - that way external modifications would be permitted, but they would happen on a copy of your object.

Another possibility is to make your class a struct, in which case it would not be possible to create references at all. This should be done with great care, because there are other implications to using value types.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I think deep down I knew the answer to this question but was hoping that it wasn't so!

Answer (score 1):

If this is OK:

```
a.CurrentData.somefunc();
```

But this is not OK:

```
var currentData = a.CurrentData;
currentData.someFunc();
```

Then syntacticaly (i.e. statically) you cannot forbid the consumption of a reference at an arbitrary time in the future.  The best you can do is build this requirement into the containing class, `myClass`.  If you surface the method, `someFunc()` as a method on `myClass`, you implicitly allow the invocation of the (internal) function only when they have a reference to `myClass` then and there.

Furthermore, if this is a good solution, you should remove the `CurrentData` property, because it is publishing a private surface area.  Propagate whatever methods `myClass` needs to expose from `CurrentData` as methods on `myClass`.